# Taping and finishing

Tags: grammar

Gypsum boards without taping and finishing.

What does taping and finishing mean?

1. Materials - tape and finishes
2. Action - taping the board and finishing the board.
3. Possibly something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gypsum boards (called "drywall" in the United States) are prefabricated sheets of gypsum between smooth paper covers; they are nailed to the timbers (studs) of interior walls and take the place of old-fashioned lath-and-plaster covering.

Once the drywall boards have been put up, it is necessary to hide the seams between them before painting, so the wall appears completely smooth and unbroken. This process is called ***finishing*** the drywall. This involves covering the seams with *drywall **tape*** and several layers of joint compound ("mud" in the US) spread very thin; once the compound has dried the surface is sanded.

The pictures below depict mounting, taping, and 'mudding' drywall. They're drawn from [familyhandyman.com](http://www.familyhandyman.com/drywall/taping/tips-for-better-drywall-taping/view-all), where you can read about this in greater detail.

[image]

Comment: Also called _sheetrock_ in the US.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean what is called [*drywall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drywall) in the US.

It is generally used for interior wall surfaces in buildings. They are mounted side by side, as you can see in the photo in the above linked page. To cover the gap between them, tape is used. That is *taping*.

*finishing* is likely some plaster or other filler that goes over the taped areas.

Your question needs more context beyond that, but it seems to mean that the gypsum boards were mounted in place and nothing else has been done.

Comment: I'm guessing that _finishing_ refers to the filling, smoothing, and sanding.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the verbs **taping** and **finishing** are related to *Action*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, and thank you for your answer! It will be even more useful if you take the time to explain your thinking, and provide dictionary or other references to help the questioner. (You can always edit your answer by clicking on the grey `edit` link.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I agree, and I also think this is a great example of a question where a dictionary is _not_ the best reference to use. Something like [This Old House](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-finish-drywall) might be better.